# Placing a Line and Text over Regular Inline Text in HTML/CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, text

I have a body of text in regular paragraph form that I'd like to annotate with footnotes, and I'd like it to be clear on what exact text from the paragraph the footnote is commenting, so I'd like to have a line (with endpoints/arrowheads/etc. if possible) over the text, with the footnote number in the center, like so:

```
   <--- 1--->                       <------ 2 ------>
   Hi, here's some text to annotate, isn't it so cool?
```

I appreciate any pointers on how to do this with HTML/CSS/JS, if it's even possible.

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/fgyVu/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way you can do it:

```css
.annotation {
  border-top: dashed 2px black;
  position: relative;
}
.annotation::after {
  content: attr(data-footnote);
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: -1.15em;
}
```

```html
<p><span data-footnote="1" class="annotation">Hi, here's</span> text to annotate, <span data-footnote="2" class="annotation">isn't it so cool?</span>
</p>
```

The `<span>` (or it could be an `<a href>` link to the footnote itself) wraps the text. By putting `position: relative` on it, that allows the child pseudo-element to be absolutely positioned relative to it.

Then the border and positioning takes care of the dashing and number. Arrowheads would be harder though.... maybe they can be done with a background image, but I haven't trued.

You'll want to make sure the `line-height` in the paragraph is big enough so the number above doesn't overlap with other lines of text.